# how do i host my own created website on google and any other search engines

Tags: google, web-hosting, search-engines

I had created a website using HTML CSS and JAVASCRIPT. How do I host it on google and other browsers so that everyone can able to use my website. Please support.

Comment: Start with reading https://www.objectiveinc.com/blog/2007/02/16/how-website-hosting-works-in-plain-english/.  I think it will help with some basic concepts of how websites works, including hosting.

Comment: [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com/new) is web hosting offered by Google, but it doesn't support custom HTML, CSS or JavaScript.   It only allows you to create pages and edit their text through an online tool.

Comment: This is really too [broadly-scoped](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for this site since that topic could easily fill an entire book.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing three terms in your question.

- To host a site, you need a server.
- Google is a search engine (it indexes sites that have been uploaded to a server, it does not host them).
- A browser is software for viewing a website such as Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera, etc. If you are referring to Google Chrome, it does not host sites; it allows access to it.

To put your site online and give everyone access, you therefore need a host. Some are free, others pay. I can't recommend one to you. You should look for "web hosting" in a search engine and make your choice.